# Query to show data checkin , checkout, breakin breakout in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I  have structure data like this, I'm using SQL Server:

| ID | User_ID | CheckinTime | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | "2022-03-25 06:30:29" | "2022-03-25" |
| 2 | 110 | "2022-03-25 12:12:31" | "2022-03-25" |
| 3 | 110 | "2022-03-25 13:02:11" | "2022-03-25" |
| 4 | 110 | "2022-03-25 17:17:21" | "2022-03-25" |
| 5 | 111 | "2022-03-25 06:32:21" | "2022-03-25" |
| 6 | 111 | "2022-03-25 12:05:11" | "2022-03-25" |
| 7 | 111 | "2022-03-25 13:01:32" | "2022-03-25" |
| 8 | 111 | "2022-03-25 17:12:51" | "2022-03-25" |
| 9 | 112 | "2022-03-25 06:32:53" | "2022-03-25" |
| 10 | 112 | "2022-03-25 17:11:21 | "2022-03-25" |
| 11 | 113 | "2022-03-25 22:10:53" | "2022-03-25" |
| 12 | 113 | "2022-03-26 07:11:21 | "2022-03-26" |

And I want to show data like this:

| ID | User_ID | Date | Checkin | Breakout | Breakin | Checkout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | "2022-03-25" | "2022-03-25 06:30:29" | "2022-03-25 12:12:31" | "2022-03-25 13:02:11" | "2022-03-25 17:17:21" |
| 2 | 111 | "2022-03-25" | "2022-03-25 06:32:21" | "2022-03-25 12:05:11" | "2022-03-25 13:01:32" | "2022-03-25 17:12:51" |
| 3 | 112 | "2022-03-25" | "2022-03-25 06:32:53" | NULL | NULL | "2022-03-25 17:11:21" |
| 4 | 113 | "2022-03-25" | "2022-03-25 22:10:53" | NULL | NULL | "2022-03-26 07:11:21" |

Anyone please help how to make this query.

Im already try using this query :

[show on 1 row, but only get max and min on that date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY4qR.jpg)

[didnt get the result like i want, not show on 1 row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtdUU.jpg)

Comment: What database are you using ? Please only tag one and do not spam

Comment: sql server. thanks, already edited.

Comment: Do you always 4 events per user per day in that sequence ?  Or you might have less or more ?

Comment: Have less or more sir.

Comment: Please include such scenario is the sample and show the expected result for those scenario

Comment: done sir, edited.

Comment: is it possible to get 1 row per users_id and date from that structure data ?

Comment: done sir. already updated.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Using the window function `row_number()` over()  and `sum() over()` in concert with a conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
Select ID = row_number() over (order by User_ID)
      ,User_ID
      ,Date = min(Date)
      ,CheckIn  = max(case when rn = 1          then CheckInTime end)
      ,BreakOut = max(case when rn = 2 and rc>2 then CheckInTime end)
      ,BreakIn  = max(case when rn = 3 and rc>3 then CheckInTime end)
      ,CheckOut = max(case when rn = 4 or rc=rn then CheckInTime end)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,rn = row_number() over (partition by User_ID Order by CheckinTime)
              ,rc = sum(1) over (partition by User_ID)
         from @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By User_ID
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: okey sir, i try.

Comment: still not correct sir.

Comment: @Dikurr11 Matches desired results.   What are we missing?